# fuzzy match in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, geolocation, fuzzy-search

I have two table in my database , agridata and geoname. I am trying to find out geoid column for names in agridata like below

`select geonameid , name from geoname where name in (select distinct district_name from agridata );`

I want to do a fuzzy match of the names as exact names are not in database. How to go about it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variety of matching algorithms (see [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/fuzzystrmatch.html)), but I'm not 100% sure they will work with an in clause. I'd imagine you really want to use a soundex join e.g.

```
select distinct g.geonameid, g.name from geoname g join agridata a on soundex(a.name) = g.name
```

or similar.

If you've got a huge match set to deal with, you may want to consider using some kind of search index such as ElasticSearch/Solr.

Answer (score 0):

Use extension for PostgreSQL called [pg_trgm](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/pgtrgm.html), implementation of trigram matching.

"We can measure the similarity of two strings by counting the number of trigrams they share. This simple idea turns out to be very effective for measuring the similarity of words in many natural languages"

I used it, it's very fast and gives great results.